# How Do I Make sure That IR Emitter signal Reached Receiver?

Tags: embedded, infrared

I am a trying to make a TV remote with one improvement that if the receiver doesn't executes the command, my remote should be able to broadcast the signal repeatedly until executed.

The problem is that, TV doesn't sends a signal if it received a IR signal or not. 
Is there anything I can do to know whether the signal was executed by TV or not ?

Comment: Bad idea. Imagine on the evening you throw it on the couch, not facing the TV.in the morning, your batteries are empty

Comment: (1) Hire cheap caregiver. Tell caregiver to use their sophisticated pattern matching skills to detect when the TV executes a remote command they are ordered to complete for you. Done. (2) Hire expensive development team. Tell them to design, build, program, and validate a new vision and pattern recognition system for a robot with an IR wand for an arm. Done. (3) Don't worry about it. When you come back, notice that TV hasn't executed the command and punch button again until it does.

Comment: Send codes 3 times, make sure you pulse 100mA and with correct protocol and use <=10 deg emitters that can bounce off walls and still reach the Rx and have adequate voltage. It should go 10m easily

Comment: In computing, the Two Generals Problem is a thought experiment meant to illustrate the pitfalls and design challenges of attempting to coordinate an action by communicating over an unreliable link. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Generals%27_Problem

Comment: Thank you. That is a very valuable input. If I ever get through this execution problem, I'll add a timeout or counter feature. @PlasmaHH

Comment: Hahaha!! I get it. I hope there's an algorithm or something to do so @jonk

Comment: Thank you @Dampmaskin. I'll read more about Two General's Problem.

Comment: I read about this problem. I am not sure how it's realted to 2 generals problem. Over here, the second general (TV) doesn't seem like broadcasting any signal or acknowledgement. @Dampmaskin

Answer (score 0):

No.

In general there is no output from a TV to indicate what channel, volume setting, etc., has been selected.

Comment: There isn't even an IR transmitter on most TVs.

Comment: Did you just said "on most TVs"? Does it mean that some televisions have IR emitters? Why would they have emitters? I am so confused. Please share some information @duskwuff

Comment: @Doherty I've never seen one with an emitter, but I can't say they don't exist. There are some weird things out there, like RF and ultrasound remote controls.